# Регулярное выражение для проверки фамилии

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста, совсем запутался,
нужно написать строку регулярного выражения для функции preg_match()

Для проверки фамилии, можно латинские и русские буквы, большие и маленькие (все), строка любой длинны
Нельзя цифры, символы, пробелы и все что не может быть в фамилии, желательно не очень сложно

Спасибо!

Comment: Воспользуйтесь поиском, уже куча таких вопросов была: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: пробелы и тире, наверное, вполне могут быть в фамилии

Comment: Фамилии бывают разными, вот например - Ивнов-О'Тул Задонский. Бывают и более сложные

Comment: Ну можно и для сложных

Comment: Я Вам советую прочитать вот [эту](https://habrahabr.ru/post/146901/) статью очень внимательно. Если Вам требуется идентификатор, то предложите пользователю придумать себе логин или генерируйте его сами на основе имени, что введет пользователь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+$/ui", $surname)
```

**UPD:**

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+$/u", $surname)
```

Спасибо, @Эдуард.

Comment: зачем у вас в шаблоне   используются строчные и прописные символы одновременно с модификатором `i` ?

Comment: вот так будет компактнее: `'/^[a-zа-яё]+$/iu'` То есть, убрать символьные диапазоны в шаблоне, и оставить модификатор `i`.